# @Lazy inject a javax.inject.Provider, why?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I just run into a piece of code that does the following:

```
@Autowired @Lazy Provider<SomeRepository> repository;
```

There's nothing that special about the `SomeRepository` type, and it seems to me we could achieve the same with

```
@Autowired @Lazy SomeRepository repository;
```

In this specific case, both the repository bean and the component that uses them are singleton-scoped. If both had different scopes, I could understand the use of `Provider`.

But that's not the case here.

Since both have the same singleton scope, a `Provider` won't get the actual repository until the caller invokes its `get()` method.

That delay would be equivalent to just lazy-injecting the repository (for what gets injected is a CGLIB proxy that only gets the actual bean at the moment of access.)

Am I missing something? Is there an actual case for combining `@Lazy` wire a `Provider` when all entities involved have the same scope?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you _certain_ there's no circular dependency involved, perhaps with custom definitions of the repository bean?

Comment: `@Lazy` causes spring to inject a proxy, what is it gonna inject here comparing to what it injects without the `@Lazy`? For me, both times it is `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$Jsr330Factory$Jsr330Provider`. WIth `@Lazy` it usually tends to be something like `...EnhancedByCGLIB...` so maybe no effect here.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- - yep, no circular dependencies. It's a pretty straight acyclic dependency graph (and a very small at that.)

Comment: @Shadov - yep, that's what I said.